# Returning variables from the tkinter function Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a function from tkinter

```
def OpenFile():
    name = askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/Batman/Documents/Programming/tkinter/",
                           filetypes =(("Image", "*.jpg"),("All Files","*.*")),
                           title = "Choose a file."
                           )
    return name
```

And where  i  am using it

```
file.add_command(label = 'Open', command = OpenFile)
```

But i need to use my variable name in the other case

```
test_image = image.load_img(name, target_size = (64, 64))
```

How  can  i get the variable from this  function and use it later, because  when i am now  trying to use it, i see message that it doesnt exist

Comment: declare it as a global variable in the functions

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It's unclear what `name` is or what the problem with `test_image = image.load_img(name, target_size = (64, 64))` is. In fact, the whole question is unclear. If the question is just "how can I get the variable from this function", then the answer is "by calling it".

Comment: @ADWAN ...please don't give bad advice. (If your advice contains the words "global variable", then it's probably bad advice.)

Comment: The `command=` option of a Button is a function that gets called by Tkinter, not by any code of yours - therefore any value it might return is meaningless.  Anything that needs to be done with the selected filename, needs to be done from within `OpenFile()` itself.